# Groovy: How to assign dynamic value to globally scoped field

Tags: groovy

By using [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) we can assign some value to the private scoped fields so that those fields are accessible globally.

I have following script:

```
import groovy.transform.Field;

def cli = new CliBuilder()

cli.usage = 'groovy Test.groovy -e <environment-name>'
cli.header = '\nAvailable options (use -h for help):\n'

cli.with {
    h(longOpt: 'help', 'Usage Information', required: false)
    e(longOpt: 'environment', 'Environment Name', args: 1, required: true)
}

def options = cli.parse(args)

if (!options || options.h) {    
    return
}

@Field def env = options.e

println env
```

When I am running it as: `groovy Test.groovy -e int`

I am getting the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at Test.main(Test.groovy)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: options for class: Test
        at Test.<init>(Test.groovy)
        ... 1 more
```

But without `@Field def env = options.e` if use `println options.e` it prints `int`.

How can I assign dynamic value to the globally scoped variable?

Comment: My small dirty solution:  

https://gist.github.com/chfstudio/51e58e56abb1e29ea53a68e7fd71197e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it so you don't have the assignment tied to the definition of the field...

```
import groovy.transform.Field;

@Field def env
def cli = new CliBuilder()

cli.usage = 'groovy Test.groovy -e <environment-name>'
cli.header = '\nAvailable options (use -h for help):\n'

cli.with {
    h(longOpt: 'help', 'Usage Information', required: false)
    e(longOpt: 'environment', 'Environment Name', args: 1, required: true)
}

def options = cli.parse(args)

if (!options || options.h) {    
    return
}

env = options.e

println env
```